# Command Pattern Implementation DRY breaks Single Responsibility Principle & Open Closed Principle

Tags: c#, dry, single-responsibility-principle, command-pattern, open-closed-principle

I'm currently implementing the Command-Handler Pattern for a service I'm designing where the Command is essentially a DTO for the Handler's `.Handle()` method.  As I begin to implement various concrete classes I realize that in order to satisfy the Open/Closed Principle and Single Responsibility Principle I may end up with thousands of Command and Handler classes, which would significantly violate the Don't Repeat Yourself Principle.

For example, part of the process I'm encapsulating requires deleting all data by `ProjectId` from 60 odd tables to reset them.  If I implement each one as an atomic concrete Command object and concrete CommandHandler object then I'll have 120 classes just for this first step.  *They will all perfectly follow SRP & OCP, however DRY takes a serious beating...*

```
public class DeleteProjectLogCommand : CommandBase
{
    public long? ProjectId { get; set; }
}

public class DeleteProjectLogCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<DeleteProjectLogCommand>
{
    public async Task<Feedback<DeleteProjectLogCommand>> Handle(DeleteProjectLogCommand command, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively I could implement a single, multipurpose, command and handler class and a `ProjectTables` enumeration could be used in place of all the discrete classes.

```
public class DeleteTableByProjectIdCommand : CommandBase
{
    public DeleteTableByProjectIdCommand(ProjectTables table, long? projectId) {}

    public long? ProjectId { get; set; }        
    public ProjectTables Table { get; set; }
}

public class DeleteTableByProjectIdCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<DeleteTableByProjectIdCommand>
{
    public async Task<Feedback<DeleteTableByProjectIdCommand>> Handle(DeleteTableByProjectIdCommand command, CancellationToken token)
    {
        switch(command.Table)
        {
            case ProjectTables.ProjectLog:
                // x60 tables
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However this would violate the Open/Closed Principle because if a new table is added, both the enumeration and every place that uses it, would have to be updated as well.  Not to mention the *smell* you get from a 60-case switch statement.

Sooo... who wins?  DRY or SRP & OCP?

Comment: How is DRY being violated? You haven't shown any repetition in your first example.

Comment: Sorry, in the first example, there would be 120 concrete classes of the format `Delete[TableName]Command` & `Delete[TableName]CommandHandler` in which they would all look identical with the exception of their name, and a line or two in the implementation of the `Handle()` method.

However, subtly, I see your point as they are different classes, they are not _actually_ doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get too tied up with acronyms. Concentrate on writing code that feels right. Atomic commands are a very good idea, but you need the right level of granularity I generally consider a command to be a complete (user) operation.

Your design of an enum and a God switch fails a basic sanity test and is not extensible without modifying the class itself, so it must be bad, right?

Comment: In this case, these are the most fine grained commands that need to be a tracked for various metrics.  They will wrap up into composite commands such as a `ResetProjectTablesCompositeCommand` that are more consumer-friendly. But I agree, that switch was kludgey, at best.

Comment: love the term "god switch"

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a RelayCommand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx

This is a command that implements ICommand, but expects to have a delegate injected for the actual work.  A number of MVVM frameworks include a RelayCommand (or DelegateCommand) out of the box.

So, you implement your command interface, and demand that an Action, or an Action<T> be injected in the ctor.  Execute triggers the action.  If you need to pass something to the action, you can use the "ofT" version, or enclose it in the delegate that you pass.

This allows you to:

- Have a single implementation of Command (or 2, if you support a generic)
- Put the actual command logic somewhere else (like in your domain object)
- If it makes sense, the command logic can actually be a Private member of your domain class, exposed by the command because you passed the delegate.

Example:

```
public class SomeViewModelOrDomainClass
{
  public ICommand DoItCommand {get; private set;}

  //ctor
  public SomeViewModelOrDomainClass()
  {
    // if your command includes a CanExecute bool, then also demand a Predicate to handle CanExecute
    this.DoItCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.SomePrivateMethod(maybeEvenAnEnclosedParam), aCanExecutePredicate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hundreds of commands and handlers don't violate DRY neither OCP, because a command contains an order for a specific use case i.e each command and handler are implementing a business use case. Do you have identical business use cases?

An example, I worked on an app which has different resource types. But I had only 1 DeleteCommand which looked like this

```
public class DeleteResource:AbstractCommand
{
    public Guid ResourceId;
    public ResourceType Type;
}

 public class DeleteResourceHandler:IExecute<DeleteResource>
{        
    private IDispatchMessages _bus;
    private IStoreResources _repo;

    public DeleteResourceHandler(IStoreResources repo, IDispatchMessages bus)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _bus = bus;
    }
    public void Execute(DeleteResource cmd)
    {
        _repo.Delete(cmd.ResourceId);
        var evnt = cmd.ToEvent();
        _bus.Publish(evnt); 
    }
}
```

Of course this is not the whole story, because the whole app was designed to work with *N* resource types and this means my entity storage was mainly a key-value store which didn't care about entity structure. Delete just needs an id.

Once the resource was deleted en event is published which is handled by the read model updater which then deletes the query data for that resource type.

When adding a new resource, I don't need to touch the DeleteCommand or the DeleteHandler nor even the entity storage. But you see, the command and handler don't work alone, they're using other components which allows them to achieve DRY and OCP. And OCP is a bit [fuzzy principle](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/03/15/the-open-closed-principle-in-review.aspx).